AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer, JwtAccessTokenConverter and JwtTokenStore was drepreciated. What can be used instead?
I am working on one application migration to the latest version of SpringBoot3. In this application, the Auth and resource servers are created using adaptors, which are deprecated along with configurers. Now I am facing the challenge of getting a replacement for this configuration. Any leads to this replacement will be very helpful, and Is it possible to replicate entire config in new version? Thank you
Added auth, resource and oauth-client dependencies.
